# HttpURLConnection's getOutputStream throwing weird IOException

Tags: java, android, file-upload, httpurlconnection, ioexception

i'm using HttpURLConnection to upload large files (up to 160MB) to server. 
there is this weird IOException coming randomly.
here is the code.

i record a video file(max. 5 min). then to upload it i starts a IntentService. which uses HttpURLConnection. here is how i initiated HttpURLConnection.

```
try {
        URL url=new URL(getString(postUrlResId));
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        //httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        httpURLConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postLength);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        //httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        //httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=*****");
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(header);

            -----------
            ----file writting to dataOutputStream 
            ---------
```

}

```
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(footer);
        RESPONSE_UPLOAD_VIDEO_BEING_PROCESSED_IN_SERVER();
        if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == 200 && httpURLConnection.getResponseMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer serverRes = new StringBuffer();
            String inputLine ;
            while ((inputLine = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                serverRes.append(inputLine);
            }
            PRINT_LOG(serverRes.toString());
            RESPONSE_UPLOAD_COMPLETE(serverRes.toString());

        }else {
            RESPONSE_ERROR();
        }   


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        PRINT_ERROR(" MalformedURLException. ");
        RESPONSE_ERROR();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        PRINT_ERROR(" IOException. may be no internet connection ");
        RESPONSE_ERROR();
    } finally {

        if (httpURLConnection != null) {
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (dataOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();  
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

now this call "httpURLConnection.getOutputStream()" sometimes throws this exception :

03-13 15:50:23.088: W/System.err(27349): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
03-13 15:50:23.088: W/System.err(27349):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:506)
03-13 15:50:23.088: W/System.err(27349):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:475)
03-13 15:50:23.088: W/System.err(27349):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
03-13 15:50:23.088: W/System.err(27349):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
03-13 15:50:23.093: W/System.err(27349):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
03-13 15:50:23.093: W/System.err(27349):    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
03-13 15:50:23.093: W/System.err(27349):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.writeRequestHeaders(HttpEngine.java:646)
03-13 15:50:23.093: W/System.err(27349):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.initRequestBodyOut(HttpEngine.java:346)
03-13 15:50:23.093: W/System.err(27349):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:301)
03-13 15:50:23.093: W/System.err(27349):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
03-13 15:50:23.093: W/System.err(27349):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
03-13 15:50:23.093: W/System.err(27349):    at com.karaoke.service.UploadService.onHandleIntent(UploadService.java:145)
03-13 15:50:23.093: W/System.err(27349):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
03-13 15:50:23.093: W/System.err(27349):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-13 15:50:23.093: W/System.err(27349):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 15:50:23.093: W/System.err(27349):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
03-13 15:50:23.098: W/System.err(27349): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
03-13 15:50:23.098: W/System.err(27349):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
03-13 15:50:23.098: W/System.err(27349):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:146)
03-13 15:50:23.098: W/System.err(27349):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
03-13 15:50:23.098: W/System.err(27349):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:473)

most of the time this usually happens first time when i start service to upload. but the occurrence is random. once this exception is thrown, if just start service again with same parameter it works fine. the occurrence of exception is increased with bigger files. i have also noticed that this issues occurs more frequently in samsung devices, i have tried with htc evo 3d, and nexus 5 also. 
can't seems to find any reason for such issue. cant find similar issue on web .

**Update:**
  so i don't exactly know why this error was appearing but when i switched my base url from  **domain name url** to **ip based url** it worked fine all the time. still would love to have some explanation on possible reason why this was happening.

Comment: "Connection reset by peer" --> you could connect initially but then the remote host closed the connection; probably a safeguard on the server side to prevent too many connections? Anyway, you have the option to retry if you receive this error. Maybe by inspecting the `ErrnoException`?

Answer (score 0):

```
httpURLConnection.disconnect();
httpURLConnection.connect();
```

I have precisely zero idea why on earth you are calling both these methods, but I suggest that removing both these lines of code will resolve this problem.

Comment: oh that was desperate attempt to stop it from using old connection.
i was told from .net team that application may be using an old connection that server has closed. wasn't actually doing it earlier.

Comment: So what is your actual question, and your actual code?

Comment: code updated.. my question is any particular reason why this exception   occurs? am i doing something wrong? there tons of example on web but cant seems to find any particular difference that causes this issue.